# Crontab keeps running

Tags: cron, execution, minute

I have the following cronjob (crontab) running on an amazon ec2 server with Linux AMI:

```
*/20 8-22 * * * php -q /var/www/html/xxx.php
```

Unfortunately, the script keeps executing every 20 minutes AFTER 23.00 hour. Could somebody explain what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with your syntax. As you wrote it, the job should execute 45 times every day, the first being at 8:00 and the last being at 22:40.

I have a hunch that the problem is timezone-related: when the job runs at 23:00, cron thinks that the local time is 22:00. If I'm right, then the job won't be running at 8:00 but will start at 9:00 or some later time.

You might be able to confirm this by setting a job like

```
* * * * * date >> /tmp/cron.date.test
```

Wait a minute then see if the date in the file agrees with your idea of what time it is. This isn't a perfect test because `date` will be making its own determination of the timezone separately from `cron`, but it will inherit its environment from `cron` so hopefully they'll agree with each other.

Comment: Thanks! I checked the date on the server and it was different indeed.